# Is it possible to make uipicker react only on swipe not on click?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uipickerview, swipe

I made UIPicker and with background on it:

(left is normal size of Picker, on the right is mine)
[image]

The problem is: when the user clicks on TextField - the picker reacts and scrolls down. Is it possible to prevent clicking, and make it to react only on swipe?

Comment: Have you tried PickerView.UserInteractionEnabled = NO ;

Comment: @TejeshwarGill Thanks, but the User needs to use Picker. I want to know, is it possible to make it react only on swipe?

Comment: your pickerview is looking smaller than the normal picker view..... how ?

Comment: @VakulSaini, Hi, it is because I put background above the Picker

Comment: Okay ... add your textfield above all view... it seems below background

Comment: @VakulSaini, thanks, but it's not working

Comment: it will work add an another UIView above all view then add your textField on this UIView ....

Comment: @VakulSaini, It works! Thank! Make an answer, that I can vote it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an another `UIView` above all view then add your `UITextField` on this `UIView`.
This will prevent the user interaction conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move your `UITextField` farther away from the `UIPickerView`. Maybe a few notches up as the users touch would cover both the views.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately there is no space above (imagine, that there are 4 more text fields and buttons)